# SVG path is not connected

Tags: jquery, html, svg, path

Hi Thanks for advance,

I have draw the svg using path, please find my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="400" width="400">
  <path fill="#E94649" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke="transparent" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="round" d="
M 71.9090909090909 366 
L 71.9090909090909 109.79999999999998 
L 143.8181818181818 109.79999999999998 
L 143.8181818181818 366 
L 215.72727272727272 366 
L 215.72727272727272 183 
L 287.6363636363636 183 
L 287.6363636363636 366 Z"

 />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

JS Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/7hvsh565/27/

but path is not connected the space has been shown for inbetween.

why the space has been shown? and how to solve?
[image]

Comment: is this you need ?.. http://jsfiddle.net/Sarathv15/7hvsh565/25/

Answer (score 0):

I have set the stroke as transparent.. that's y the line was not displayed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="400" width="400">
  <path fill="#E94649" fill-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke="gray" stroke-linecap="butt" stroke-linejoin="round" d="
M 71.9090909090909 366 
L 71.9090909090909 109.79999999999998 
L 143.8181818181818 109.79999999999998 
L 143.8181818181818 366 
L 215.72727272727272 366 
L 215.72727272727272 183 
L 287.6363636363636 183 
L 287.6363636363636 366 Z"

 />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Check the below link http://jsfiddle.net/7hvsh565/28/